# Loop pedal Vs. interface. Which is better for looping?

Tags: looping, looper-pedals

I am not a gear geek and wish to buy as little gear as possible.

I am now just starting to learn the guitar and am practicing with the electric guitar without an amp (and I think I will keep this way for quite a long time although not quite sure).

Having said that, one thing I wish to have is a looper.

I already have a one-year-old laptop so I am considering to buy an interface just for looping.

Buying a loop pedal means an amp also needs to be bought.
Buying an interface means loop pedal needs to be bought to trigger a loop with a foot(not sure really).

But I can't say for sure I won't be doing more than looping in the future so I am inclining toward an interface.

What would you buy in this kind of situation?

Comment: Many multi-effect pedals these days are also audio interfaces, and have headphone outputs and cab sim, everything you need to do your looping, recording, practicing at home and performing live, in one box.

Comment: you say as if a pedal is a simpler tool. But when I look it up, it is more expensive. The cheapest is 100 dollars. Where as an interface is 60 dollars. Am I looking at wrong things?

Comment: You're right, if you want to minimize the price too, multi-effect might not be optimal. It might be optimal if you want to minimize the amount of equipment you buy (e.g. for easy transportation, or due to limited storage space), which is what you indicated in the question.

Comment: The simplicity of loop pedal is that it has just one dedicated button to start and stop recording, without need for apps, connecting separate foot controller if you want to use it hands free, dealing with latency, etc. And yes, you can get an entry level looper for way less than $100 and I doubt the $60 interface is a good one.

Comment: I think you must mean loop pedal versus something like a VST plug in emulating a loop pedal that you would use through a computer audio interface and DAW.

Comment: If I were an inexperienced beginner, I would buy something and then learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a question of “loop pedal VS. interface”. They are two things that perform different functions.

A loop pedal allows you to create, layer and play back loops. It produces a signal which must be converted to actual sound, just like an electric guitar does.

(From M-Audio:) Audio interfaces convert microphone and instrument signals into a format your computer and software recognize. The interface also routes audio from your computer out to your headphones and studio monitors. Interfaces typically connect to your computer via USB cables.

An interface can take the sound from a looper and allow you to hear it through headphones or speakers that are connected to it. If you have no interest in interfacing with a computer an interface is not the only option you have.

Instead of an interface, you can get an inexpensive practice amplifier which will allow you to hear what the looper pedal produces. These usually also have a headphone jack as an option.

Another option is to look for a multi effects pedal that has a good looper built in. Most of these have headphone jacks so this is probably the only stand alone option if you are looking to buy a minimal amount of gear and don’t mind using headphones or earbuds. One advantage to this is you will also have many other useful effects available to you in the same unit.

Finally, you can also bypass the looper entirely  and create and layer loops in a different way using your guitar, an interface and DAW software. If you choose this route you will be creating loops on the computer in a desktop screen environment. This is completely different than using a pedal that you start and stop with your foot and may not be what you are looking for. It would be good for experimenting at home but not practical for performing.

Comment: To add on this, there are looping softwares that can be used in combination with an audio interface, emulating a full fledged looper. Of course, an additional foot controller is usually useful in that case..

Comment: I recommend a Zoom G1 Four pedal for beginners. It has a looper function and a rhythm machine, as well as all imaginable types of effects and amp simulations, all of which sound good. And it has a headphone output and aux input. That pedal will take a beginner a loooooong way before anything better is needed. Currently €99 at Thomann, the price has gone up something like 30% in three years.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, this is pretty "opinion based." And perhaps eventually you'll want all these things. But consider researching a bit into the differences of what they can do. When I first tried a looping pedal, I imagined something like this: "I'll record one bar of a shaker and set it looping, then an 8-bar chord change on top of it. At some point I'll hit a pedal and kick in the entire 16-bar chorus that I prerecorded." But all the looping pedals I looked into had only one "length of loop" at a time; that is, if I wanted an 8-bar chord progression I had to record 8 bars of shaker, and could only pre-record 8 bars of chorus. Meanwhile, my perception is that I could lay all of this out Ableton Live and trigger whatever I want.

Generally, it's good advice to invest in your *musical* creativity first, and upgrade your equipment once it's holding you back. Getting your computer involved opens up a huge array of possibilities, but maybe it's too many variables at first. You might consider "hitting the limits" of what you can do with a simple looper first.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down:

"I am not a gear geek" — So you do not enjoy messing with technology and reading fat manuals.

"wish to buy as little number of gears as possible" — keep the total budget down beyond what most players consider mandatory, "without an amp"

"one year old laptop" — good computer.

"trigger a loop with a foot" — Kinda means you want to just loop with no real interest in recording

That all said, here's my take:

An interface will be very cheap
(such as this [2 Channel USB Audio Interface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C6KCFZRM) on Amazon)
but you will need to futz with audio software for EVEY loop, and for EVERY loop layer.  Meaning you will need to do some learning on a DAW and will basically need to make a library of songs to play over to do what you want.  It will not be in "real time", you will constantly need to be playing with the computer.

A loop pedal and small amp will cost a bit more
(such as this [Twin Looper](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YCB8GQD), and this [Rechargeable Mini Amplifier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B9M1CQBZ)).

But you will be able to play a progression, loop it, solo over it, layer over it.  Then delete it play another, solo over that one, etc.  Basically have a ball with the guitar in your hands the whole time, controlling everything with the 2 foot switches.

SO: Cheap interface.

- Pros — You can then record and get into that, cheap
- Cons — You will constantly fuss with it.  Steep learning curve.

Musical solution — looper and amp

- Pros — Many loopers can record and save recording to computer so you can still do the studio thing.  Real time looping possible.  Far easier learning curve for basic loops.
- Cons — More $$, still have stuff to learn

I would propose a looper that can record and a small amp.  Then at lease you will have an amp, which will considerably increase the joy you can extract from an electric guitar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you are considering a computer audio interface and then using a VST type plugin for the loop effect.

If you plan on not using an amp, that would seem to be the only way to get effects.

I think a big part of the question is how you plan to use the effect. I've seen many people use looper pedals in *live* performance where they use the foot pedals while playing and also make hand adjustments to the knobs also while in performance. Actually, it's impressive how people can manipulate the pedal mid-performance. Kind of like an organist using bass pedals and changing organ stops.

Anyway, if you want to make mid-performance adjustments to the effect, you should think that through with a VST effect. I've only used VST plugin effects where I had to turn the effect on/off and adjust it via the mouse, which was not practical for me while playing. I had to set it and leave it until done recording a part. I understand there are MIDI footswitches to control VST effects, but that would mean buying more gear and doing research to know exactly what you want.

If the issue about the amp is only about money, and not about a worry of disturbing the neighbors, the potential upside to an amp with foot pedal effects is the relative ease of using them while mid-performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need an amp as well as a looper - untrue. Some, (maybe the more sophisticated, complicated) looper pedals will have a headphone out port, so negating the use of an amp. But using a cheap and cheerful fx pedal *with* phones out will solve that one. If that's to keep the neighbours sane, it's a good idea, and future-proofing you for when you maybe do get an amp, for live playing, where you'll need both hands (and feet!) to loop. Again, a lot, if not most, these days, of loopers will have drum tracks and effects, all of which can be listened to through cans.

You ask for personal preference, which actually is a little out of bounds on this site, but I went for loopers, as taking a computer to gigs isn't my idea of fun.

Comment: I have three dedicated looper pedals, and none of them has a headphone output. I also checked 20 cheapest looper pedals in Thomann's catalogue and none of them had a headphone output either. Among the 30 cheapest loopers, there was one combo ampsim/looper, which had a headphone output. I conclude that _looper pedals_ almost never have headphone outputs. Only some multi-function multi-effect/looper units have headphone outputs. There are some affordable multi-effect+amp-sim pedals which have a headphone output as well as a looper function, such as the Zoom G1 Four.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica -  seems you're right, it's only my RC-300 that has a phones out. I'll re-phrase the answer. Thanks.